# Azure China Billing report API endpoint

Tags: azure-billing-api, azure-china

Consumption APIs for Azure China.

Which API do I need to call for China which is similar to **https://consumption.azure.com?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For web direct customer, we have this [article](https://docs.azure.cn/en-us/billing/billing-get-usage-information,%20both%20English%20&%20Chinese%20support) to guide to download usage details from account center; while for EA customer, [this article](https://docs.azure.cn/zh-cn/enterprise-agreement-billing/enterprise-agreement-billing-download-usage-report) (Chinese only) gives the proper guidance:

For billing API – feature wise, China have the same function on EA portal and process is the same, however, we use China azure URL instead global, e.g. **ea.azure.cn**.

We summarize China azure billing API [here](https://docs.azure.cn/zh-cn/enterprise-agreement-billing/enterprise-agreement-billing-download-usage-report).